# Then at the end of sentence

Tags: adverbs

Is it correct to say something like: "I'm available at 5 p.m. If it works for you, let's schedule our lesson then"? Does it sound natural? How would native speaker say something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "[Then](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/then_1?q=then)" can be a pronoun meaning "at that time", so this sentence works well.